# Animation duration doesnt work in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-animation

I'm working on a new app and I'm trying to do basic animations such as TranslateTo(x,y,duration, easing). the problem is that I'm trying to move a block from point A to point B, but I can't see the moving animation, it just appears in point B instantly even though I did set the duration to 5000 ms ...
I just don't know how to fix that.
I'm using visual studio 2019

This is what I used :
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

boxView2.TranslateTo(boxView2.TranslationX + 200, 0, 5000, Easing.CubicOut);
        }

the expected result is that the moving animation should be visible but the actual result is that the box just pops up from A to B instantly

Comment: I tried changing the Android's version but I still have the same issue

Comment: When I removed the `await `before method `TranslateTo`, I couldn't reproduce this question .What's version of your xamarin form nuget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue in the previous Xamarin Forms on Android related to this. Updating XF tot he latest 4.2 version (4.2.0.848062) fixed it on our side